# Is it possible to detect how long hasn't user type command

Tags: linux, shell, daemon

I'm working on Linux shell and I'm trying to write a script, which is just like a trigger as below:

```
if user hasn't typed any command for 2 min
    execute some executable file
fi
```

If I can have such a script, I could make it as a daemon process. For example, I could make my system do this:

```
if user stops typing command for 2 min
    shutdown -h now
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to be careful... for example what if the command itself takes longer than 2 minutes to execute? Shutting down the system is likely unwanted in this instance.

The only way to get this behavior is from within the shell application (not as a separate entity / daemon), where you know about the state -
e.g: `GETTING_COMMAND`, or `EXECUTING_COMMAND`...

In `bash` you can use the [`TMOUT` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html):

> TMOUT
>
> If set to a value greater than zero, TMOUT is treated as the default timeout for the read builtin (see Bash Builtins). The select command (see Conditional Constructs) terminates if input does not arrive after TMOUT seconds when input is coming from a terminal.
>   In an interactive shell, the value is interpreted as the number of seconds to wait for a line of input after issuing the primary prompt. Bash terminates after waiting for that number of seconds if a complete line of input does not arrive.

Be aware that this will also affect any calls to `read` or `select` that the script makes.

Something like this would do what you're after:

```
export TMOUT=120
bash
shutdown -h now
```

If you're developing your own shell, then of course you could use something like `select(2)` while taking the user's input.